# inVerse (from Converse.js) plugin to OpenFire doesn't work on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, openfire, converse.js

We have an internal Windows server with OpenFire 4.5.1 with inVerse 6.0.1 Release 1 installed.  The plugin works great from Chrome browser and Edge browser, but I really need it to also work from IE11, if possible.  When initial page loads, there are 2 errors:

[IE11 console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiQOU.png)

If you can't see the image: 1. Syntax error converse.min.js (55,35487) 2. 'converse' is undefined inverse (43,17).

Looks like a show-stopper.  Not sure how or if a fix is available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [the Converse Github issue](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+ie), we can see that there have many threads about Converse plugin not support IE browser. Such as: [Support for IE 11 and iOS Safari 9.3](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/issues/1377)

According to these issues, we can know that Converse uses quite a few features not supported by IE11, not just arrow functions. So, perhaps this plugin doesn't support IE browser or it needs to install some Polyfill. You could contact Converse developer team and ask them whether there have a workaround, or feedback this issue to [Converse Issue forum](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+ie).